# Is it possible to use the HERE SDK (Premium) for iOS with Xamarin?

Tags: here-api

we are wondering if it is possible to use the HERE SDK with Xamarin for iOS Project? Has anyone used HERE SDK in Xamarin so far?

Comment: A few people have tried Xamarin with the Android SDK without success.

Comment: @DavidLeong Is this still true?

Comment: I no longer work on HERE SDK, but from the latest SDK I can see the answer is 'NO"

Answer (score 0):

In general Xamarin Bindings are not supported by HERE Mobile SDK.